# Get all the Items from Generic List by Specific value

Tags: list, linq, c#-4.0

I have one generic List where i have many items. There some of the items have specific value like true, Here i need to run one linq query to have those specific items based on items value=true able to segregate in those items in var variable.

I have tried using List.Find, FindAll, Contains

```
public class FilterControl  
{  
    public bool IsItem1 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem2 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem3 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem4 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem5 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem6 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem7 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem8 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem9 { get; set; }  
    public bool IsItem10 { get; set; }  
}  

List<FilterControl> listFilters = new List<FilterControl>(){  
   new FilterControl() { IsItem1 = false, IsItem2 = false, IsItem3 = true, IsItem4 = false, IsItem5 = true, IsItem6 = true, IsItem7 = false, IsItem8 = true, IsItem9 = false, IsItem2 = true },  
};
```

I have tried like below:

```
var getAllItemsWchValueTrue = listFilters.Where(a => a.IsItem1 == true).Select(a => a.IsItem1).FirstOrDefault();
```

But in this code i can check only one item which value is true or false.
I need here to check whichever items have value true those items i want to have in Var variable.

Comment: The code you've posted is *just* creating the list. What LINQ queries did you try, and what happened? Is there a reason why items 3-10 are `int` properties rather than Boolean properties? (That's a bit odd for a property with an "Is" prefix.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have posted the wrong type for items properties. Now edited, All are bool only.

Comment: used linq query but i am getting each items value not like based on the matching value get all the items.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the comment, but you should show us *exactly* what LINQ query you tried, as well as what you expected and what happened, in a [mcve]. Please be very specific about it - just saying that you tried "a LINQ query" doesn't give us enough information to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I added the linq query which i tried so far and put comment about what is my actual requirement.

Comment: try this
`var getAllItemsWchValueTrue = listFilters.Where(a => a.IsItem1 == true ||  a.IsItem2 == true ||   a.IsItem3 == true ||   a.IsItem14== true  and so on ....)`

Comment: When you add code to a post, please don't say it's a runnable Javascript snippet unless it actually *is*. I've fixed it now.

Comment: What do you mean by "those items i want to have in Var variable"? If one element of the list matches one condition, and a different element matches another condition, what would you expect to be in the list? I'm finding it really hard to understand what you're expecting here. Again, a *complete* example (not just individual snippets) would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet, whatever linq query i used in my post where i am checking for one item. Is there any way to check all items value in one shot which value is true. Whichever items  value is true those items i need separately. Hope you understand.

Comment: @V.Prasad: No, I don't understand what you mean by "Whichever items value is true those items i need separately." You can check multiple conditions in one `Where` call as per Wamiq's comment, but I suspect that isn't what you need - but as you still haven't provided a [mcve], we can't help you. I'm afraid I'm done here - there's no point in us both getting frustrated with each other simply because I can't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/kjvWPC

```
    List<FilterControl> listFilters = new List<FilterControl>(){
   new FilterControl() { IsItem1 = false, IsItem2 = false, IsItem3 = true, IsItem4 = false, IsItem5 = true, IsItem6 = true, IsItem7 = false, IsItem8 = true, IsItem9 = false }};

    var getAllItemsWchValueTrue  =  listFilters.Select(p=>
            {

         List<string> items =new List<string>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in p.GetType().GetProperties()){
         var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
         if (type == typeof (System.Boolean) && (bool)prop.GetValue(p, null))
         { 
            items.Add(prop.Name);
         }
        }

        return items;
       }).SelectMany(q=> q);
```

A more tidy way https://dotnetfiddle.net/6dxa17

```
var getAllItemsWchValueTrue = listFilters.Select(p =>
        {
            return p.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => (prop.PropertyType == typeof (System.Boolean)) && (bool)prop.GetValue(p, null)).Select(prop => prop.Name);
        }

        ).SelectMany(q => q);
```

Comment: Can i have the query like i commented on JonSkeet?

Comment: @V.Prasad I understand what you meant do you want just the item name ?

Comment: Yes Warmiq. I need those items having value true.

Comment: Awesome answer Wamiq, This is what i was looking for. Thank you for understanding my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) is what you're looking for. You can submit a lambda expression as parameter to filter by a specific property.

Comment: I already tried where condition where i can have each item with there value one by one. I need here solution like in one shot based on value=true related items should get segregated from the list.